# how do I add ghcjs to path?

Tags: haskell, path, ghc, cabal, ghcjs

In order to install [ghcjs](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs) I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04

No problem with requirements.  `alex` and `happy` where automitcally installed.  Then:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs.git
$ cabal install ./ghcjs
```

However, I cannot call ghcjs from terminal.  Perhaps it's not in PATH?

```
$ ghcjs-boot --dev
ghcjs: command not found
```

How do I add to path?

Comment: Do you have `~/.cabal/bin` in your path? GHCjs should be there, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cabal` installs binaries in `$HOME/.cabal/bin` on Linux like systems. To add that to your path you can put

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.cabal/bin"
```

in your shells configuration file (which would be `~/.bashrc` if you're using Bash).